# How do I add an RSS feed in Evolution?

Tags: 11.04, evolution, rss, blog

I want to add a couple of blogs (mainly blogspots) to evolution. I already installed the RSS plugin and looked up what url I need to give in for the rss feed (via http://davesaunders.net/2009/01/how-...-blogger-blog/

In this way, I give in the following url to follow the blogspot

http://dingoo-scene.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss

But every time I do so, evolution seems to load something but hangs on 0%. Finally, I need to kill it because it doesn't react any more. I also tried the other options given by the first URL, but it doesn't help. NOw, how can I read RSS feeds in evolution please because it all seems so difficicult (in Kontact it worked like a charm I remember)

Comment: can you confirm in your question that this is the plugin you have used? http://gnome.eu.org/evo/index.php/Evolution_RSS_Reader_Plugin

Comment: Yes indeed, it is this plugin I'installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be the victim of [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-rss/+bug/773763)

*A short excerpt of the bug summary:*

```
I use ubuntu 11.04.
The version of evolution is : 2.32.2-0ubuntu7
The version of rss-evolution is : 0.2.2-0ubuntu1

When I open evolution without option, It freezes after 2 seconds, but when I open evolution with the command "evolution --disable-eplugin", It works.
So I think plugin evolution-rss is the problem.
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to be an answer to my question. Is there another way to read RSS feeds in Evolution?

Comment: Don't know about plugin for evolution, but you can use Liferea Feed Reader from the repos.

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion, but I figured out this myself in the meantime :-). A handy suggestion: add the rss feeds to google reader, then you can import this through liferea with your google account. In this way, you don't need to add them over again in your different devices

Answer (score 1):

Adding RSS feeds to Evolution can be done by going to `Edit->Preferences->News & Blogs`

[image]

Or, press the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and scroll down to select `News & Blogs`.

Next, Select `Add` and paste the URL into the field provided.

A new folder called "News and Blogs" will be created in the "On This Computer" section of the Evolution folder tree where your subscription feeds will be updated.

[Source](http://gnome.eu.org/index.php/Evolution_RSS_Reader_Plugin:Setup_Feeds)

Comment: You must first install the plugin for this to work: `sudo apt install evolution-rss`